# WebBrowser Control is opening PDF files outside of the control

Tags: vb.net

I have a webbrowser control on one of my forms that has been working correctly on **Windows 7**. I use it to display **images** and **pdf** files inside the application when they attach files. After testing this on **Windows 8**, the pdf files are opening outside of the webbrowser control. Images open up fine in the webbrowser control. Is there a way to stop it from opening outside the application?

I'm using the .Navigate to the file:

```
  webPreviewNew.Navigate(MyFilePath)
  webPreviewNew.Visible = True
```

Comment: Works on my machine™, you probably forgot to install the Adobe cr*pware.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same thing.  I believe it is a security change in IE 11 that prevents it from being opened inside the browser if I remember correctly.

This may not fit your case, but I tracked when there were open processes of the adobe reader, excel, etc... and simply closed them after a timeout.  We were concerned about multiple browser windows and open documents hanging out there consuming resources on shared workstations.